# PHP MySQL - Move record to another table, Select, Insert, Delete

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables with the same structure. Iam attempting to move an entire record from one table to another and then delete from the source table. If i execute the two statements seperately it works, i.e. select and Insert 2. Delete.

How could I combine these two sql statments so that both statements are within one, and can be esxecuted one after another. Here is mysql statement so far, Its not executing

```
$q="  INSERT INTO archived (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id='$id') ;

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id='$id'; ";
```

Comment: You can't, you need to do two seperate queries or use [`multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: You can do this on `mysqli` only. That too using `mysqli::multi_query` as @Fred-ii- suggested.

Comment: you can move data from one table to another table using [SELECT INTO] and The [INSERT INTO SELECT] statement copies data from one table and inserts it into an existing table

Comment: what about deleteing the record from the table1?

Comment: currently selecting and inserting the record in the new table is not an issue, its combinging the statement to delete the record from the first table

Answer (score 1):

You can execute multiple SQL statements using one SQL statement string by seperating them by semi colon and passing the final statement to [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) function.

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');
// username is user , password is pass ,connecting to the demo database on the localhost host:
if($con->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql =   "INSERT INTO archived SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id='$id';";
$sql .=  "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id='$id'; "; 

if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
else{
    echo "Executed successfully";
}
```

You can do

```
function mysql_multiquery($queries,$conn)
{
    $queries = explode(";", $queries);
    foreach ($queries as $query)
        $query = mysql_query(trim($query),$conn);

}
```

Call function

```
mysql_multiquery($sql,$conn);
```

Comment: where do i put the connection $con?

Comment: HI dont i have to put the $con in the sql statement i,e. if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql, $con))

Comment: is there a way of doing this without mysqli, instead just mysql. This is because my remaining system isnt working with mysqli

Comment: you will have to use mysqli extension for executin multiple queries in one go , mysql_query() doesn't suppport multiple SQL statements..

Comment: mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.....http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to send only one command from php, write a stored procedure with the two queries.  Then your php command executes the procedure.